# Output in Ruby gem Trollop

Tags: ruby, parsing, rubygems

This is an example output from Trollop, the Ruby option parsing gem
v0.0.1a

```
Options:
      --input, -i <s>:   Input file location (required)
     --output, -o <s>:   Output file destination (required)
      --cores, -c <i>:   Number of cores (default: 4)
  --threshold, -t <f>:   Threshold (default: 1.0)
        --version, -v:   Print version and exit
           --help, -h:   Show this message
```

It's the best option parser available because it's so small and neat, but I really don't like the centre justification of the help message. I have never seen this kind of output before in programs I have used and would much prefer it to align the options to the left, and then the descriptions to the left in a second column. Is it possible to make it do this?
Cheers

Edit:
In the latest version of trollop this is formatted with a left justification now. It's great! Although I did get used to the centre justification after a short time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Trollop is now at version 2.0.0 and help formatting is still hardcoded in the code. You can hack [trollop.rb](https://gitorious.org/trollop/mainline/source/43d5a92971f41079c77f4b0b13bcc8d25dcba197%3alib/trollop.rb#L425) if you wish to augment to output formatting.